# How really was the Satayuga?

Tags: yuga, time, krita-yuga

We all know there are 4 Yug.
Satayugs, TretaYuga, DwaparaYuga, and Kaliyuga.

Through Ramayan, we got to know more about TretaYuga, through Gita we got to know about DwaparaYugs, and we are living in Kaliyuga so we know about Kaliyuga.

But I can't find out any proper description of Satayuga. The only thing I know about Satayuga is that there weren't any paapi and paap.

I want to know more about the age of Satayuga, like how was the livelihood and the environment during Satayuga?

Comment: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03148.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was earlier asked by Devaraja Indra to lord Brihaspati.
He asked about the characteristics of all the yugas.
Devaguru answered the question as follows.
(I'm only quoting the part of krta yuga)

> 10-18. Kṛta Yuga is said to consist of seventeen lakh twenty-eight
> thousand years, when Janārdana remains white in colour, and Dharma has
> all its four feet intact. (Then) the earth is full (in all respects).
> The people are devoid of lust and anger, fear and hatred. All people
> are long-lived with quiescent souls and full control over the
> sense-organs. They are as tall as five Tālas (Palms). They are
> brilliant and well-informed. Men’s childhood extends to sixteen
> thousand years. Thereafter the youth extends to thirty-two thousand
> years. It is only thereafter that old age befalls men slowly. The
> ultimate life span is one lakh years. In certain cases it extends even
> beyond that.

From here, he tells especially about the livelihood of people and environment of krta yuga.

> All living beings, animals, birds and beasts speak the
> divine language. They are not mutually inimical. Serpents sport about
> along with mongooses, cats along with mice, deer with lions, and owls
> with crows. Even without being cultivated, the earth (though not
> ploughed) produces much vegetation consisting of cereals, pulses,
> barleys etc. They are tasty and able to accord strength and
> nourishment. The trees bear fruits in all the seasons with excellent
> flowers and fruits, good leaves etc. They are devoid of thorns and
> they resemble Kalpa trees.
>
> 19-29. Cows yield the desired tasty milk at all times. The butter and
> ghee produced from it is enormous. No woman becomes a widow there, nor
> an unfortunate wretch. There is no Kākavandhyā (a woman with but one
> child) there bereft of sons. There is no woman without virtue (all
> women are virtuous). Birth and death befall men in due order. A father
> never sees death of his son. People who die do not become ghosts. No
> one is compelled to stay in Naraka. No one suffers pain due to
> sickness. All Brāhmaṇas are well-versed in Vedānta. They regularly
> study their Vedic Mantras. They are delighted in expounding the Vedas
> and well-versed in the knowledge of Brahman.
>
> Kṣatriyas make one of them the king with great devotion and loyalty.
> They enjoy the earth righteously following his behests.
>
> Vaiśyas are engaged in the various activities befitting the Vaiśya
> community such as breeding of cattle, buying and selling of
> commodities etc.
>
> O most excellent one among Suras, Śūdras are extremely faithful. They
> do not do anything except service unto Brāhmaṇas and twice-born ones.
>
> No one is base-born there nor is there anyone of mixed caste. No
> impure one and no one of the fifth caste is to be seen there on the
> earth.
>
> Men there perform Yajña (Fire-worship), Yajana (Yajña on behalf of
> others), Dāna, Vrata, Niyama etc. and pilgrimage without any
> expectations of personal benefit thereof.

From this description, we know the livelihood of people and environment in krta yuga.

Source: [Skanda Purana- Nagara Khanda- Chapter 27: Characteristics of the four yugas](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493337.html)

Comment: @Prateek chaubey you can also see this..shlokas 32 to 54..It also describes a little about people in krta yuga. 
 https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57236.html

Comment: I have a doubt , as per my knowledge people take birth in specific caste or species according to their karma , done by them in previous lives. But in Satyayug how was it defined that who will be born as human and who will take birth as cow or any other animal.

Comment: Actually time is cyclic in nature, so we have been living countless lives till now(present birth) and based upon the sanchita karma accumulated in the previous births and the prarabhda karmas which are to be experienced in next life, it is decided that in which group of species one should be born. So based on the previous birth of the people and the species of satyuga, it must have been decided. The calculation part though... That in which species one should be born next.... is little tricky as it's not calculated by humans. :)